# Use Office Add-ins (js) to import Mail Merge Data

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office365, mailmerge, office-js

How do you import data as a MS Word (2016) Mail Merge Datasource using Office Add-ins programmatically using JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

as of July 2016 this is not supported on the Word JavaScript API. would be great to know more details about your scenario and specific APIs you would like to use (or are using in VSTO and would like to see on Office.js).

Would be great if you can post the details here:
https://officespdev.uservoice.com

thank you!